# Spring Security Login Processing url not available

Tags: spring, spring-security, jsf-2

I have a project where Spring is used with JSF (using PrimeFaces). Up until now we have used xml configuration for Spring Security, but I have been tasked with porting it to java based configuration.

I have now went from the xml config in `applicationContext.xml` :

```
<!-- Security Config -->
<security:http security="none" pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**"/>
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"/>

    <security:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" 
        login-processing-url="/do_login"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"
        username-parameter="email" 
        password-parameter="password"/>
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/login.xhtml"
        logout-url="/do_logout"
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="userDetails" class="com.madmob.madmoney.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></bean>
<bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg name="strength" value="10" />
</bean>
<bean id="authSuccessHandler" class="com.madmob.madmoney.security.UserAuthenticationSuccessHandler"></bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetails">
        <security:password-encoder ref="encoder" />    
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

and the following from `web.xml` :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

To the following java based configuration :

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserAuthenticationSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
        throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT email, passowrd, enabled FROM app_user WHERE email = ?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT role_name FROM role WHERE role_id = (SELECT role_id FROM user_role WHERE email = ?)")
        .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login.xhtml").loginProcessingUrl("/do_login")
        .failureUrl("/login.xhtml").successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
        .usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password").permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login.xhtml").logoutUrl("/do_logout")
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

        // temp user add form
        // TODO remove
        http.antMatcher("/userForm.xhtml").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.EnumSet;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    protected  EnumSet<DispatcherType> getSecurityDispatcherTypes() {
        return EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.FORWARD);
    }
}
```

Login worked fine on the xml based configuration, but since switching if I try to login Tomcat returns 404 with : `The requested resource is not available.`

All pages are also accessible regardless of logged in or not.

Below is my login form :

```
<h:form id="loginForm" prependId="false" styleClass="panel-body">
    <div>
        <p:inputText id="email" required="true" label="email" 
                    value="#{loginBean.email}" styleClass="form-control f-75"
                    placeholder="Email Address"></p:inputText>
        <h:message for="email" styleClass="validationMsg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"/>
    <div>
        <p:password id="password" required="true" label="password"
                    value="#{loginBean.password}" placeholder="Password"></p:password>
        <h:message for="password" styleClass="validationMsg"/>

        <h:messages globalOnly="true" styleClass="validationMsg" />
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"/>
    <p:commandButton id="login" value="Log in"
                    actionListener="#{loginBean.login}" ajax="false"/>
</h:form>
```

and the login method in my backing bean :

```
/**
 * Forwards login parameters to Spring Security
 */
public void login(ActionEvent loginEvt){
    // setup external context
    logger.info("Starting login");
    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    // setup dispatcher for spring security
    logger.info("Setup dispatcher");
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
            .getRequestDispatcher("/do_login");

    try {
        // forward request
        logger.info("Forwarding request to spring security");
        dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(), 
                (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());
    } catch (ServletException sEx) {
        logger.error("The servlet has encountered a problem", sEx);
    } catch (IOException ioEx) {
        logger.error("An I/O error has occured", ioEx);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("An error has occured", ex);
    }

    // finish response
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
}
```

This is running on Java 1.8, Tomcat 7, Spring and Spring Security 3.2.5, JSF 2.1, Primefaces 5

Things I have tried since encountering the problem :

- Added the `SpringSecurityInitializer` since initially I only used `SecurityConfig`.
- Tried using default Spring Security url(`j_spring_security_check`), by not  specifying the processing url and forwarding to that instead.
- Disabled csrf
- Added `getSecurityDispatcherTypes` method to `SpringSecurityInitializer` to match the config from web.xml
- Various other smaller things while searching for a solution

Comment: You bootstrap Spring Security without any configuration. You should call the `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer(Class<?>... configurationClasses)` constructor instead of the default no-args constructor. Or if you have another means of loading the `ContextLoaderListener` add the configuration class to that.

Comment: `ContextLoaderListener` is defined in my `web.xml` so if I call that constructor I get an exception because there is already a root application context, I don't know how else I can add the config then. Note as far as I'm aware the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation should handle this or am I missing something? (the package is part of the component scan, but I had the same issue when manually defining the bean in xml too)

Comment: If your configuration isn't loaded, you can put as many annotations on it as you want without any effect. So make sure the configuration is loaded (although something is loaded else your app would fail to start with a message stating that a bean named `springSecurityFilterChain` wasn't defined).

Comment: I have confirmed through debugging that all three the `configure` methods in `SecurityConfig` do get executed so I assume that means it does get loaded. If not is there any other way I can check to confirm that it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. The problem lies with :

```
http.antMatcher("/userForm.xhtml").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
```

This was just purely incorrect chaining of the methods on my part by the looks of it. I don't really understand why it caused the issue with login processing url not being found instead of just unexpected access behavior, but I changed that entire snippet of the method to look as follows :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/userForm.xhtml").permitAll() //TODO remove temp user add form
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login.xhtml").loginProcessingUrl("/do_login")
    .failureUrl("/login.xhtml").successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
    .usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password").permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login.xhtml").logoutUrl("/do_logout")
    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
}
```

This of course also makes a lot more sense, but I primarily separated them initially because as the comment specifies, the `userForm.xhtml` is temporary.